# SQL 2008 pull in Child records

Tags: sql-server-2008, parent-child

I am trying to return data for someone in the following format from a SQL 2008 query -

```
ProductID, ProductTitle
  ServiceID, ServiceTitle
  ServiceID, ServiceTitle
ProductID2, ProductTitle2
  ServiceID, ServiceTitle
ProductID3, ProductTitle3...
```

So the product table lists the products and then the product service table will have several services assigned to one product ID. Is the above even possible? Or something similar?

Comment: the data you provide isn't clear

Comment: so what output do you want? \

Comment: I am sorry for being unclear. I have a products table and then I have a ProductService table. The Product service table will have one or more services assigned to the same productID from the Products table. I am trying to get a parent child relationship. So have the products listed out with the service assigned to each product as a child record. I am not even sure if that is possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is very possible, and it's a good practice when you're just beginning SQL,

this is how your database/table structure should be:

t_Products : ID, Name, Price

t_ProductService: 
ID
serviceName
productID

the ID in t_Products should be primary key and

the productID in t_ProductService should be the foreign key of the ID in t_Products

Edited:
You need to use join, there are a lot of join in SQL,

```
SELECT * FROM t_ProductService ps
INNER JOIN t_Products p
ON ps.ProductsID = p.ID
```

Comment: That is how I have the table structures setup for the two tables. How would I pull in the data as a child like above?